# Teachable Machine Voice Control in React (Commands exec more than once)

Tags: reactjs, machine-learning, use-effect

I'm attempting to use a Teachable Machine voice model to control "next" and "previous" functions on a page. The "next" command needs to trigger state change one time, as does the "previous" command. More often than not, positive detection of a voice command causes 2, 3 sometimes more state changes before it finally stops.

The state changes are assembled by iterating forward and backward over an array. Saying "next", for example, grabs an ID from the next index position in the array, and re-renders the page components according to the other attributes assigned to this ID. The problem is that when the "next" command is heard, I am rapidly iterating several indices forward or backward instead of just one.

I have tried everything under the sun to mitigate this effect to no avail. I am beginner. Any help I can get with this will be enormous, as this is a final project for a course I'm taking.

Here is the useEffect:

```js
function VoiceDetection(props) {
  const { poseIncrementer, startSequence } = props;
  useEffect(() => {
    let recognizer;
    createModel().then((model) => {
      recognizer = model;
      recognizer.listen(
        (result) => {
          // console.log(result)

          const scores = result.scores; // probability of prediction for each class
          const classLabels = recognizer.wordLabels();
          const allPredictions = [];

          for (let i = 0; i < classLabels.length; i++) {
            // const classPrediction = classLabels[i] + ": " + result.scores[i].toFixed(2);
            const classPrediction = {
              word: classLabels[i],
              probability: Number(result.scores[i].toFixed(2)),
            };
            allPredictions.push(classPrediction);
          }

          allPredictions.sort((a, b) => b.probability - a.probability);
          const match = allPredictions[0].word.toLowerCase();

          if (match === "next" && poseIncrementer) {
            poseIncrementer(1); // This needs to happen ONE TIME
          }
          if (match === "begin" && startSequence) {
            startSequence();
          }
          if (match === "previous" && poseIncrementer) {
            poseIncrementer(-1); // This needs to happen ONE TIME
          }
        },
        {
          includeSpectrogram: true, // in case listen should return result.spectrogram
          probabilityThreshold: 0.75,
          invokeCallbackOnNoiseAndUnknown: true,
          overlapFactor: 0.5, // probably want between 0.5 and 0.75. More info in README
        }
      );
    });

    return () => {
      if (recognizer) {
        recognizer.stopListening();
      }
    };
  }, [poseIncrementer, startSequence]);
}
```

And here is the function invoked by useEffect:

```js
const poseIncrementer = (direction) => {
  setState((prev) => {
    let nextPoseIndex = prev.poseIndex;

    if (
      (direction > 0 && prev.poseIndex < prev.poseArray.length - 1) ||
      (direction < 0 && prev.poseIndex > 0)
    ) {
      nextPoseIndex += direction; // This needs to happen ONE TIME
    }

    return { ...prev, poseIndex: nextPoseIndex };
  });
};
```

Comment: the only thing that comes to mind is that somehow more than one recognizers are listening and therefore firing multiple updates, try wrapping the `postIncrementer` definition in `useCallback` to avoid changes in the `useEffect` dependencies, same for `starSequence`; maybe the hook is executing more than once

Comment: This is a reasonable approach, thank you. I am attempting it now, but I'm unclear as to how to implement this suggestion. What are my dependencies in this scenario?

Comment: the `useEffect` hook depends on `[poseIncrementer, startSequence]` if you don't wrap the definition of those functions in `useCallback` they will be created in every render; hence the `useEffect` will be called multiple times

Comment: Thank you for your help. The problem is solved now!

Comment: please remember to post an answer with the details of the solution and accept it so everyone else knows how to solve it